# iOS14 HLS audio stream not pulling User defined URL links in metadata (ID3 tag) swift

Tags: swift, ios14, id3-tag

My app is a radio app, which uses HLS audio streaming. The app reads metadata from the stream and shows song information like album name, artwork etc.,This seems working fine till iOS 13 but when tested the app on iOS 14, I do not see the artwork url (song image url) coming over. After I debug, i found that the metadata is not showing the artwork url at all, which embeds in ID3 tag (as User defined URL link frame: WXXX).
I am not sure why this happened only on iOS 14, with the same stream sending same data. Is there anything that changed in iOS 14 , in terms of reading the metadata? Is someone has this problem? Please help me out

Comment: Which api do you use to access the tags?

Comment: Hi @fruitcoder i am using AVPlayer in my app. so, I am using AVMetadataItem to read the tags

Comment: Hm we use the timed metadata as well but we're not using the WXXX frame and haven't found any regression in iOS 14. Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: @fruitcoder yes, I am testing on real device and simulator as well. Thanks

Comment: @Himabindu - were you able to solve your issue ?